# Find most occurring value in a group

Tags: clickhouse

I want to find the most occurring value per group.

I tried using top(k)(column) but I get below error: 
Column class is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY.

For example:
If I have table test_date with columns(pid, value)

```
pid, value
----------
1,a
1,b
1,a
1,c
```

I want result :

```
pid, value
----------
1,a
```

I tried `SELECT pid,top(1)(value) top_value FROM test_data group by pid`

```
I get the error: 

Column value  is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY
```

I also tried with `anyHeavy()` but it only works for values that occur more than in half the cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT pid,topK(1)(value) top_value FROM test_data group by pid
```

Answer (score 6):

This query should help you:

```sql
    SELECT
        pid,
        /*
        Decompose the query in parts:
        1. groupArray((value, count)): convert the group of rows with the same 'pid' to the array of tuples (value, count)
        2. arrayReverseSort: make reverse sorting by 'count' ('x.2' is 'count')
        3. [1].1: take the 'value' from the first item of the sorted array
        */
        arrayReverseSort(x -> x.2, groupArray((value, count)))[1].1 AS value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pid,
            value,
            count() AS count
        FROM test_date
        GROUP BY
            pid,
            value
    )
    GROUP BY pid
    ORDER BY pid ASC
```

Comment: This works but the query is complex. I see that there is topK function and it does the same.

Comment: I intentionally ignored *topK* by this [reason](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/#topk-n-column): "This function doesn't provide a guaranteed result. In certain situations, errors might occur and it might return frequent values that aren't the most frequent values".